# Aspose cell: How to add a new column with name (header name) to existing Listobject?

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose-cells

I have a situation where I need to add a new column to the existing ListObject and also update the new column header value. Can anyone help on this?

I am using aspose 7.4.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code to add a new column with name updated.
I hope this is correct.

```
ListObject tableObject = GetTableObject(tableName);
tableObject.Resize(tableObject.StartRow, tableObject.StartColumn,     tableObject.EndRow, tableObject.EndColumn + 1, true);
tableObject.ListColumns[tableObject.EndColumn - 1].Name = "UpdatedName";
```